# Preciso da maior e menor nota da matriz, mas quando dou print sai um vetor com as três notas o que faço? estou usando o min e o max

Tags: python

```
def mostrandomatriz():
   for l in range(0,5):
       #estética 
       print(f"Aluno {l+1}")
       print("|-----|")
       #leitura da coluna e impressão da matriz
       for c in range(0,3):
          print(f"|{matriz[l][c]:^5}|")
       #estética   
       print("|-----|")
   
print ("======================|")
for l in range(0,5):
   for c in range(0,3):
    matriz[l][c]= float(input(f"Aluno {l+1}| {c+1}ª Nota = " ))#Receber todas as notas
   print ("======================|")
print("\n")

mostrandomatriz()

Maior = max(matriz)
Menor = min(matriz)

print(f"Maior Nota = {Maior} Menor Nota = {Menor}")
```

Comment: o código está incompleto. Como você definiu essa matriz?

Comment: matriz = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

o `min` e `max` built-in do python não é bom pra procurar mínimos e máximos em arrays multidimensionais. Use essa funções do pacote `numpy` e vai dar certo.

```
import numpy as np

def mostrandomatriz():
   for l in range(0,5):
       #estética 
       print(f"Aluno {l+1}")
       print("|-----|")
       #leitura da coluna e impressão da matriz
       for c in range(0,3):
          print(f"|{matriz[l][c]:^5}|")
      #estética   
       print("|-----|")

matriz = np.zeros([5,3])

print ("======================|")
for l in range(0,5):
   for c in range(0,3):
    matriz[l][c]= float(input(f"Aluno {l+1}| {c+1}ª Nota = " ))#Receber todas as notas
   print ("======================|")
print("\n")

Maior = np.max(matriz)
Menor = np.min(matriz)

print(f"Maior Nota = {Maior} Menor Nota = {Menor}")
```

Comment: eu faço em um android

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, dá para ir verificando o maior e menor no mesmo *loop* que lê as notas:

```
maior = float('-inf')
menor = float('inf')
for l in range(0,5):
    for c in range(0,3):
        nota = float(input(f"Aluno {l+1}| {c+1}ª Nota = " ))
        if nota > maior:
            maior = nota
        if nota < menor:
            menor = nota
        matriz[l][c]= nota

print(f"Maior Nota = {maior} Menor Nota = {menor}")
```

---

Claro que se quiser, também pode verificar só depois de ler:

```
# ler a matriz...


# verifica o maior e menor
maior = float('-inf')
menor = float('inf')
for linha in matriz:
    for nota in linha:
        if nota > maior:
            maior = nota
        if nota < menor:
            menor = nota

print(f"Maior Nota = {maior} Menor Nota = {menor}")
```

---

Claro que também dá para usar `min` e `max`, porém eles não funcionam com listas de listas, então ou você percorre elas e chama `max` separadamente para cada linha, ou então "achata" a matriz:

```
# Opção 1: com itertools, "achata" a matriz
from itertools import chain
maior = max(chain(*matriz))
menor = min(chain(*matriz))

##############
# Opção 2: verificar o maior/menor em cada linha, e depois obtém o maior/menor dentre esses
# obtém o maior dentre os maiores de cada linha
maior = max(max(linha) for linha in matriz)
# obtém o menor dentre os menores de cada linha
menor = min(min(linha) for linha in matriz)
```

O problema dessas soluções é que elas precisam percorrer a matriz duas vezes: uma para achar o maior e outra para achar o menor (que é o mesmo problema da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/499055/112052)). Mas eu acho desnecessário, e prefiro a primeira solução que sugeri: obter o maior e menor no mesmo *loop* que lê os dados, assim você não precisa ficar percorrendo a matriz várias vezes à toa.

---

Por fim, vale lembrar que listas em Python são dinâmicas e você não precisa criar uma com as dimensões corretas, pois ela pode ir crescendo conforme a necessidade. Ou seja, para ler os dados e adicionar as notas na matriz, você poderia fazer:

```
matriz = [] # começa como uma lista vazia
print ("======================|")
maior = float('-inf')
menor = float('inf')
for l in range(1, 6):
    linha = [] # linha começa vazia
    for c in range(1, 4):
        nota = float(input(f"Aluno {l}| {c}ª Nota = " ))
        if nota > maior:
            maior = nota
        if nota < menor:
            menor = nota
        linha.append(nota) # adiciona a nota na linha
    matriz.append(linha) # adiciona a linha na matriz
    print ("======================|")
```

<sup>*Se bem que também poderia ser usado um dicionário, cuja chave seria o nome/identificador do aluno, e o respectivo valor seria a lista de notas...*</sup>

E para mostrar a matriz, você pode percorrê-la sem precisar de `range`'s fixos:

```
def mostrandomatriz():
   # para cada linha da matriz, começando "l" com 1 (assim não precisa somar 1 no print)
   for l, linha in enumerate(matriz, start=1):
       print(f"Aluno {l}")
       print("|-----|")
       for nota in linha: # para cada nota desta linha
          print(f"|{nota:^5}|")
       print("|-----|")
```